# Lenovo T60 maximum resolution issue with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, thinkpad

I just replaced the LCD on my Lenovo T60 running windows 7.  The LCD works just fine but windows is reporting the maximum resolution as 1024x768 when it should be 1280x1024.  I've tried uninstalling both the video card and display from device manager as well as downloading the latest drivers from lenovo, but windows refuses to let me set the correct resolution.  I even tried messing with the registry with no luck.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: P.S Why do you say that the LCD panel should be 1280x1024 native? Have you explored the possibility that whoever replaced your LCD replaced it with a 1024x768 panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a Linux Live CD such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download), and see if you can make the resolution go any higher.

I replace and use hundreds of LCDs in laptops and I only had this issue once when I was shipped ones with the wrong resolution! It is possible that the same has happened.

If you are able to go to a higher resolution in Ubuntu or your live cd of choice, come back and I will try to help further.

Comment: this turned out to be the issue (they shipped me a display with the wrong resolution).  I got a replacement and it works fine now.

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Sometimes it is a low tech answer that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The LCD is not feeding back the correct information (in this case, the native resolution) to the graphics card.

You got two options, and I am going to state the better one first :

1. Identify the LCD manufacturer and model, find a corresponding driver (need not be from the same manufacturer - e.g Dell and Lenovo sometimes uses the same LCD panels), and force-install that driver if necessary. You might want to call whoever replaced your LCD for more information.

Alternatively, you can try force installing a driver for a monitor that you know have the same resolution as your current monitor, thereby tricking the graphics card to accept that information and output the native resolution.

2. Use [Powerstrip](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/ps.htm). It's not free, but it is used widely to set resolutions, as well as control the many options related to graphics.